# 2019 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

The [nomination period for the 2019 election](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) was scheduled to end in 15 minutes. However, in order for the election to proceed, it is necessary to have at least one more candidate running than there are slots. This allows for there to be actual voting phases, so that the community can actually show that they support the candidates who are running. We have extended the deadline for nominations for an additional seven days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless someone wants to take on the responsibility. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: If you're an active user of the site, regardless of reputation, I encourage you to run.  The existing mod team is happy to mentor if you're new to moderation.

Answer (score 3):

Really? No one else wants to step forward?

I can think of a couple of good candidates.

If I were to step forward as a candidate and then decline to serve if elected, would people cry foul?

Comment: If there were only two candidates, we ran the election and you won and then you declined to serve, we'd just have to start over from scratch. While we do call up runners-up in some cases, we don't in cases where there's only one other candidate. So, it'd just delay the new election. It'd be great to have additional candidates but please don't step up if your plan is to step down should you win. I've run in elections strategically before but always with the expectation that I'd stick around if I were elected... I just knew that outcome was unlikely. :/

Comment: I was mostly kidding. If the nomination period is extended, I'll put myself forward, with the intention of serving.

Comment: Alive and well?