# Election check-in - Who's interested in stepping up to help being a moderator here?

Tags: discussion, election

Web Apps last had an election [just a year ago](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/4) which ended with insufficient moderators. At the time, I opted to try out [three-vote closure/reopening](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/cancelling-election-lets-try-something-else-testing-three-vote-question-clos?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C20.6972) here rather than running the election again. Right now we have an opportunity to run an election for the site, and after consulting with the mods, it sounds like it is a good time to try again, hopefully with two or more candidates.

To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail again due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts. My plan, currently, is to have an election starting in two weeks, so this is also acting as an advance announcement of the election.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Answer (score 8):

I might be running, if no-one else steps up. Most of my activity lately has been reviewing and editing rather than answering, and in general I'm more of a flag-handler and being-a-general-Stack-Exchange-knowledge-base rather than a subject matter expert or community builder, but if the community doesn't mind that, I'm happy to be your janitor annex information source.

Comment: Go Glorfindel!!

Answer (score 5):

I'm willing to run for a moderator position

Comment: You'd have my vote seeing how well you perform on this site...

Comment: Go Ruben!!!!!!!