# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election what official page is missing - why nomination was prolonged, what will happen if same occasion will happen again, for how long nomination period could be prolonged

Comment: @Kos: I think that the same said one year ago applies here [2019 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4683/88163)