# 2023 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2023 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Start an election for moderator positions during a moderator strike without so much as acknowledging the weather? Classy.

Comment: This election was planned before the strike, and this specific question was automatically posted by a bot. There's nothing classy about it.

Comment: @Caleb It's true that at first instance, it doesn't look good that this post was published during a SO/SE community strike, but as [pppery said](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5057/2023-community-moderator-election?cb=1#comment5451_5057), the election was scheduled before the incident that triggered the strike. I don't think this issue should be included in the same bucket as the other company-community relation issues. Note: I posted this using my alt. account, ref. [Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange Moderators Strike](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5055/).

Answer (score 2):

## Congratulation, Blind Spots, and thanks to all who voted!

(Final 6th election stats added at the bottom of the table)

---

If you haven't voted yet, please do it now! So far, 145 users voted. The vote count is below the vote count compared to previous elections, but there is still time, as the election ends in 3 days.

| Election | Year | Data | Voters | Visited Site | Visited Election Page | Voted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2011 | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 2 | 2012 | 1,255 voters were eligible, 359 visited the site during the election, 278 visited the election page, and 167 voted | 1,255 | 359 | 278 | 167 |
| 3 | 2013 | 1,748 voters were eligible, 532 visited the site during the election, 386 visited the election page, and 232 voted | 1,748 | 532 | 386 | 232 |
| 4 | 2019 | Cancelled | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 5 | 2020 | 5,257 voters were eligible, 699 visited the site during the election, 566 visited the election page, and 254 voted | 5,257 | 699 | 566 | 254 |
| 6 | 2023 | 5,852 voters were eligible, 780 visited the site during the election, 845 visited the election page, and 145 voted (on Jun 18th, 2023, UTC TIME ~20:00) | 5,852 | 780 | 845 | 145 |
| 6 | 2023 | 5,854 voters were eligible, 922 visited the site during the election, 942 visited the election page, and 166 voted (final numbers) | 5,854 | 922 | 942 | 166 |

Comment: Interestingly, there are more visitors to the site and the election page this year than in 2020, but fewer votes have been cast.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: We got a new nomination, just in time to continue with the election process. Let's wait for the official announcement.

---

So far, there is only one nomination. As there is one vacancy, we need at least one more valid nomination; otherwise, the election might be canceled, as occurred with the 2019 election.

Reference

- [2019 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4683/311306)
- [Cancelling election - let's try something else? Testing three-vote question closure](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4687/311306)

Comment: I may have sabotaged it by flagging the previous candidate's prose.

Comment: @BlindSpots Please don't feel that way. AFAIK, there were two previous nominations. None of them look good enough to be considered seriously; the first was clearly posted as a joke / trolling the election, and the second had multiple problems, starting with the introduction, which looks to be a nomination for a site focused on creating web applications instead of using them and not including all the required questions. On the other hand, there were more comments besides yours. P.S. The second had multiple parts reported as fake by Hugging Face GPT-2 detector.

Comment: By the way, I'm wondering why we don't have more questions on Web Applications about how to use ChatGPT. Writing a prompt might be seen as writing spreadsheet formulas / custom functions. I think that we could handle cases that don't require specialized  LLM knowledge.

Comment: Web Apps SE could benefit from three-vote question closure, since it has few active users who have the reputation to vote to close/reopen.

Comment: @Wicket "*I'm wondering why we don't have more questions on Web Applications about how to use ChatGPT.*" I believe we have quite a few well-received questions tagged [[tag:chatgpt]], but some of them were closed by Ruben, a community moderator, and later deleted by the Community bot (roomba). This meta post asks about the issue and links to other relevant meta posts: [2023 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5054/7584).

Comment: Still considering those questions, from my POV, webapps.se have received very few questions, i.e. compared with the weekly questions tagged [tag:google-sheets].

Comment: @galacticninja Webapps [already has 3-vote closure](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4724/312586). That doesn't help when the last 3 close vote reviewers date back to March.

Comment: @pppery Thanks for linking that meta post. I didn't know that. I thought it wasn't in effect because most of the recently closed questions I've seen here are unilaterally closed by a mod. Since we already have three-vote closure, I think the moderators should ease up on the unilateral question closures. Relevant meta post: [Do the moderators plan to close most questions on this site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/7584)

Comment: @galacticninja agreed, and mods should especially quit unilaterally closing  question  when it goes against the community consensus. [Do moderators care about the community consensus?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5060/18147)

Comment: If anyone has any questions for me, I am happy to answer.  Any Q&A comments made on the nomination page became  hidden onece the election began.

Comment: @BlindSpots I have a question. I made a meta post about it here: [2023 Moderator Election candidates: What's your approach to moderation in the face of community disagreement? Will you prioritize community consensus?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5061/7584)

Comment: @BlindSpots thanks, do you think that [showing research is a requirement when posting a question on WebApps.SE?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5005/18147) Requirement means that if the OP doesn't show research, then the question must be closed.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt  I don't see that as a must-close reason.